# ASP.Net UpdatePanel, want to have html-tag as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

This is my problem, I have one textbox, one button and one label. Everything is inside an updatepanel. Let's say I want to test if a valid html-tag is entered in the textbox when I press the button. In the code-behind I have a method for that.

Everythings works just fine, except when I actually enter a html-tag in my textbox. If I test < html>, it works. But not if I test .

So my question is, doesn't the updatepanel accept html-tags as parameters? Because my breakpoint for the button_click doesn't triggers.

Sorry for my bad english.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're in an UpdatePanel you aren't seeing the real error here...if you just remove the UpdatePanel and do a full postback you will.

Since you're entering an HTML tags, ASP.Net is stopping the postback because you're hitting Event Validation, which prevents symbols like `<` and `>` from being entered to prevent scripts attacks on your site.

[See here for troubleshooting this and learn about your options](http://blogs.msdn.com/stcheng/archive/2009/01/16/aspnet-asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-troubleshooting-info.aspx).  The short version is that by default you **cannot** enter HTML tags in the field, more specifically, you can't enter `<` and `>`